# how to change FileReader to url

Tags: javascript, xlsx

I want to read xlsx files using js. 
This is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#input-excel').change(function(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    console.log(reader.result);
    var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
    console.log(data);
    var wb = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array'});
    console.log(wb);
  }
});
});
```

It gives me the xlsx in an array object, exactly what I need.
But I don't want the user to load the file,
I want the file to be loaded from a URL.
Does someone know how to do it?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the same XLS file, you can use ajax to load it. Almost similar:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: URL_TO_FILE
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var wb = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array'});
    console.log(wb);
  });
```

Comment: Thank You!
But now I'm getting:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: That's the problem with CORS. You can try to enable it from $.ajax function first. If it still doesn't work, you have to modify a little your web server's config to enable CORS there. You can read more here:
https://enable-cors.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/sahan/Desktop/data.json"));
    ObjectNode objNode = mapper.convertValue(obj, ObjectNode.class);
    System.out.println(objNode);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Could you add some text?